# Variable present in an object

Tags: vba, excel, variables, object, shapes

Does a variable have to be specifically *available* (help on terminology?) within a `For...Next` Statement

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For i = 10 To 13
        ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle " & i + 24)).Height = 43.5
        ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle " & i + 24)).Width = 43.5
        ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle " & i + 24)).Top = 20.25
        ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle " & i + 24)).Left = 20.25 + 44.5 * i
    Next i
```

When I've attempted to declare the `Shape` as an `Object` I was expecting the variable to pass through the object, but it seems to not have:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim shp1 As Object    

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set shp1 = ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle " & i + 24))

    For i = 10 To 13
        shp1.Height = 43.5
        shp1.Width = 43.5
        shp1.Top = 20.25
        shp1.Left = 20.25 + 44.5 * i
    Next i
```

Do I need to declare the `Shape` as an `Array` or some other type of `Object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some unnecessary code lingering from a recorded macro. The `Range(Array(...))` functions are only necessary if you are selecting more than a single shape at one time. The macro recorder includes these because that is easier than determining if more than a single shape has been selected and it is only marginally redundant.

Since you are using a progressive *i* in the calculated value for the `.Left` property, you will have to deal with these one at a time. There is no way I know of to magically pass a changed *i* value into a calculated `.Left` value differently for various shapes without cycling through them and using the *i* on the appropriate shape at the appropriate time.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by *"pass an Argument through the Sub"* but I've included an optional parameter to the sub's declaration.

```
Sub Reshape1(Optional iRECT As Long = 10)
    Dim i as long
    For i = iRECT To 13
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle " & i + 24)
            .Height = 43.5
            .Width = 43.5
            .Top = 20.25
            .Left = 20.25 + 44.5 * i
        End With
    Next i
End Sub

Sub Reshape2(Optional iRECT As Long = 10)
    Dim i as long, shp As Object
    For i = iRECT To 13
        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle " & i + 24)
        With shp
            .Height = 43.5
            .Width = 43.5
            .Top = 20.25
            .Left = 20.25 + 44.5 * i
        End With
        Set shp = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub

Sub Reshape()
    Call Reshape1()
End Sub
```

I've supplied two variations on what you supplied in your question. Hopefully you can use enough of these to get what you are intending.

Comment: is there something additional I need to do? When I attempt to run either of these the 'Run Macro' Pop-Up displays? Searching through the names I don't see `Reshape1` or `Reshape2`.

Comment: @PlainsWind - The optional parameter is declared as a long with a default value, not a variant with no default so they won't show up in the macros dialog. I had (wrongly) assumed that you were attaching this to a button or running it from a calling sub. Either remove the optional iRECT parameter and fix the `For ... Next` so it doesn't reference it or use a calling macro sub. My apologies, as mentioned I was unclear on what you wanted by *passing an argument*.

Comment: I removed the comment about the `Argument` through the `Sub` as I believe this was throwing off the true intent of my question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is what I was looking for - spot on!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of `i` **after** the assignment to the `shp1` object will have no effect on the `shp1` object, even if the object is defined with the variable `i`.

```
Set shp1 = ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle " & i + 24))

For i = 10 To 13
```

Object are created as a specific place in memory, assigning to the object variable establishes this object by *evaluating* the statement.  Later, changing a variable like `i` will have no effect on the instance of the object already created.

Set the `shp1` object *inside* the loop:

```
For i = 10 to 13
    Set shp1 = ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle " & i + 24))

    ...
```

Comment: I kept my info as the example but moved the `Set` inside of the `For...Next` loop but did not get the results I was seeking